# Html CSS 3 columns layout fixed 100% height not work in safari if content not equal height (work in chrome)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have 3 columns layout with fixed height 100%.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="top-block-60">
            top-block-60-px
        </div>

        <div class="content-left-full-height">
            --
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="center">
        <div class="top-block-60">
            top-block-60-px
        </div>
        <div class="content-center-full-height">
            <ul>
                <li>List item</li>
                <li>List item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div class="top-block-60">
            top-block-60-px
        </div>
        <div class="content-right-full-height">
            --
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


html, body, #left, #right, #center { height: 95%; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #6b6b6b; overflow: hidden;}
#content {height: 95%; width: 98%; min-width: 1000px; max-width: 5400px; font-size: 0; margin: 0 auto;}
#left, #center, #right { display:inline-block; font-size: 12pt; height: 100%;}
#left { width: 20%;}
#center { width: 40%;}
#right { width: 40%;}

.clear {clear: both;}

.top-block-60 { width: 100%; height: 60px; border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;}

.content-left-full-height { display:inline-block; width: 100%; overflow: auto;}
.content-center-full-height { display:inline-block; width: 100%; overflow: auto;}
.content-right-full-height { display:inline-block; width: 100%; overflow: auto;}
```

Each column should have top fixed content and scrollable content.
Solution work in the Google Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/ALLxW/ (see in chrome or image bellow)
[image]

But not in the Safari.

If content of columns is equals, it work:
[image]

If i place any content one of the columns, it is broken:
[image]
no matter which column contain content:
[image]

Can not find solution for Safari at all.

css. html, js here: http://jsfiddle.net/ALLxW/
[full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/ALLxW/embedded/result/) (different in Safari and Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a float: left to left, right and center. So the css looks like this:

```
#left, #center, #right { display:inline-block; font-size: 12pt; height: 100%; float: left}
```